# Can I run a XAML Unity App in 3D mode using the Mixed Reality

Tags: xaml, unity-game-engine, 3d, virtual-reality

I'm using the latest Unity version (2017.3.0f3) and check my player enable Window Mixed Reality. After building a new project from Unity with Build Type XAML, I see nothing but a black screen. When I use Build Type D3D, it works well. 
Is there any problem with XAML type. Almost Mixed Reality tutorial on Microsoft, they recommend using D3D.

Comment: IIRC, a Mixed Reality application *must* be in D3D for it to be a "hologram" type render, instead of a floating 2D window. Don't know what's up with the "black screen" though.

Comment: I've tried with XAML, the MR application loaded few seconds then it had crash and stop :-?

Comment: Without a stack trace I can't even begin to speculate